# Using ADD, SUB, MULT, and DIV to place certain values into boxes?

Tags: algorithm, math

Today I had an interview for a developer job and I had to do this aptitude test...
I got stuck one 2 questions:

```
box 1  box 2  box 3
 A      B      C
```

How to put A in each boxes with only those 4 operator (ADD, SUB,MULT and DIV)?

```
box 1  box 2  box 3
```

You have the numbers 1,2 and 3 that can be in either box1 box2 or box3 but we don't know in which is which... How to put 7 in box 3 ?

Can someone can explain me how to do it ?
ps: syntax is: ADD,1,2,3 => box3 = box1 + box2

Thank you

Comment: Did you have to remove B and C from their respective boxes, so that each box ended up with only one letter: A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first question, you can set boxes B and C equal to 2A by just storing A + A in each:

```
ADD 2, 1, 1
ADD 3, 1, 1
```

Now, just subtract A from each box:

```
SUB 2, 2, 1
SUB 3, 3, 1
```

This results in A stored everywhere.  The resulting program is thus

```
ADD 2, 1, 1  // Box 1 = A  Box 2 = 2A  Box 3 = C
ADD 3, 1, 1  // Box 1 = A  Box 2 = 2A  Box 3 = 2A
SUB 2, 2, 1  // Box 1 = A  Box 2 = A   Box 3 = 2A
SUB 3, 3, 1  // Box 1 = A  Box 2 = A   Box 3 = A
```

For the second question, one cute trick would be to divide some box by its own value to put 1 into it.  For example:

```
DIV 1, 1, 1
```

Now, let's put 2 into box 2 by doubling the contents of box 1 and storing it there:

```
ADD 2, 1, 1
```

Now, let's put 4 into box 3 by doubling the contents of box 2 and storing it there:

```
ADD 3, 2, 2
```

Next, add 2 to box three by adding in the contents of box 3.  This makes box 3 hold 6:

```
ADD 3, 3, 2
```

Finally, add 1 to box three by adding in the contents of box 3.  This makes box 3 holds 7:

```
ADD 3, 3, 1
```

The total program is thus

```
DIV 1, 1, 1   // Box 1 = 1  Box 2 = ?  Box 3 = ?
ADD 2, 1, 1   // Box 1 = 1  Box 2 = 2  Box 3 = ?
ADD 3, 2, 2   // Box 1 = 1  Box 2 = 2  Box 3 = 4
ADD 3, 3, 2   // Box 1 = 1  Box 2 = 2  Box 3 = 6
ADD 3, 3, 1   // Box 1 = 1  Box 2 = 2  Box 3 = 7
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good job! The second can require one fewer step, no? DIV 1, 1, 1; ADD  1, 1, 1; ADD 2, 2, 3; ADD 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @kasavbere- I'm not sure I see how this works - can you elaborate on this?  Your approach must be different from mine, because it looks like you're using the values of Box2 and Box3 without knowing their values.